# My Android app suddenly requires permissions not set in AndroidManifest.xml. Why?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have an app that have only had minor changes the last couple of years. Yesterday I released a bugfix to Google Play, and noticed that my app suddenly requires 5 new permissions:

- android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
- android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
- android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE maxSdkVersion=18
- android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
- android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

I have not made any changes to AndroidManifest.xml, so these 5 permissions are not listed there.

I'm using Google's billing library (com.android.billing) for in-app purchases. This might have been automatically updated by Android Studio.

I have upgraded these libraries as well:

- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1 -> 22.2.0
- com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1 -> 22.2.0
- com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0 -> 7.5.0

Does anyone know why this happened?

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER**

@ahmad-nawaz is right, and his answer led me to figure this out. Here is a more detailed answer to my question:

The library that wanted the extra permissions is **Google Play Services**.

In Google Play Services version 6.5 and onward, you can (and probably should) define which specific API you need, instead of just importing the whole package.

In my case, I was just using play-services-analytics, so I changed this in my build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

to this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
```

After this change, all the 5 permissions mentioned in the original question disappeared.

Here is the complete list of the individual APIs of Google Play Services: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Comment: this really helped me i have the same issue and i just imported `play-services-analytics` instead of whole package and all of sudden permitions for get account and use accounts vanished :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are coming from Libraries you used. Android studio merge the libraries permissions into app.