# READ and WRITE external storage permissions gets added when not specified in manifest file

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-developers-console

I am trying to upload my app to the Google Play store.
The app was created using Xamarin Forms.
After I upload, `READ ACCESS EXTERNAL STORAGE` and `WRITE ACCESS EXTERNAL STORAGE`.
I have checked my manifest file and neither 'write' nor 'read' is checked in it.

Can it be because of any nugget packages that might require external storage?

**Details:**

- min android version - 4.3
- install location - internal only
- Target android version - API 24 (automatic)

Thanks.

Comment: https://medium.com/glucosio-project/how-libraries-can-silently-add-permissions-to-your-android-app-620911d7de6c#.n7jyxzuk9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Android app suddenly requires permissions not set in AndroidManifest.xml. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660853/my-android-app-suddenly-requires-permissions-not-set-in-androidmanifest-xml-why)

Comment: @Jason oh, thank you so much. The link helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Removing this line from AssemblyInfo.cs fixed it.

```
// Add some common permissions, these can be removed if not needed
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)]
```